# how to pass two php session variables via ajax to a another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a shopping cart and the in the one page where i show the items i have to add a feature for filter the available items for their prices.So i thought to use my session variables to do that but i dont have a proper understand to do it in that way since i am a beginner.But i managed to do it in a hardcoded way.when the user select the check box for price range i make a ajax call and it include the relevant php file after filtering.But since it is not good can any one show me a better way to do that?
here are my php session variables in item.php file
`include("config.php");
$dress=$_REQUEST['dress'];
$catg=$_REQUEST['catg'];
$subcatg=$_REQUEST['subcatg'];`

### Here is my ajax code

```
 <script>
function showUser()
{


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}



xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
//alert(str);
document.getElementById("xx").checked = false;
xmlhttp.open("GET","dd.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

## here is my dd.php file u can see ther i hardcoded values for filtering the items in the query

```
<?php

    include("config.php");   
//error_reporting(1);
$catg=$_SESSION['catgg'];
$subcatg=$_SESSION['subcatgg'];

   $sell=mysqli_query($con,"select * from items where catg='2' and subcatg='kurtas'  and price BETWEEN '1000' and '1500'");
   echo"<form method='post'><table border='0' align='center'><tr>";
   $nn=0;
    while($arrr=mysqli_fetch_array($sell))
   {
   $i=$arrr['itemno'];
    if($nn%3==0)
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    }
   echo "
   <td height='280' width='240' align='center'><div class='col-md-3 item-grid simpleCart_shelfItem ' style='width:100%'>
                    <div class=' mid-pop'><div class='pro-img'><img src='admin/itempics/$i.jpg'  class='img-responsive' height='200' width='200'><br/>

 <b>Item No:</b>".$arrr['itemno'].
   "<br><b>Price:</b>Rs&nbsp;".$arrr['price'].
   "<br><b>Description:</b>".$arrr['desc'].
   "<br><br><a href='indexone.php?con=12 & itemno=$i'><img src='images/MetalPlakDa5new.gif' width='70' height='20'/></a>
   <a href='indexone.php?con=14 & itemno=$i'><img src='images/view7.jpg' width='70' height='20'/></a>
   <div class='zoom-icon '><a class='picture' href='admin/itempics/$i.jpg' rel='title' class='b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search icon '></i></a>
                        <a href=''><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right icon'></i></a></div></div></div></div></td>";
  $nn++;

   }
      echo "</tr></table>
       </form>";
       ?>
```

Comment: Why would you store the variables in a php session? Most of the shopping carts use GET parameters. Imagine when a customer wants to bookmark a particular product for a future use or email it to a friend then if you use sessions and ajax that won't work. Make sure you start the php sessions by calling session_start() before accessing or storing the session variables. (after next line of <?php tag)